# Добавление Info.plist в проект QT5

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, macos, qml

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Недавно начал изучать QT

В запущенном приложении при попытке включить камеру вылетает приложение и выдает "Отчет об ошибке".
Изучив разные способы добавления Info.plist в проект ни один не сработал.

Пробовал:

Добавил сам файл Info.plist (взятый из папки с примерами QT)

1. в файле *.pro прописывал

   `ios { QMAKE_INFO_PLIST = ios/Info.plist }`
2. Так же пробовал

   `QMAKE_INFO_PLIST = MyInfo.plist`
3. Последнее что пробовал как в одном из примера QT
   создал файл shared.pri и в файл `include(../shared/shared.pri)`

Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно исправить эту ошибку или что я неправильно делал в своих попытках

Comment: Внизу сообщения (Termination reason) описывается проблема

Comment: Если у вас не существует файла с plist то создайте его и заполните согласно документации (https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из [официальной](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtmultimedia-ios.html) документации

Поскольку Qt Multimedia для iOS использует камеру, Info.plist, которая назначается с помощью **QMAKE_INFO_PLIST** в файле проекта, должна содержать ключ **NSCameraUsageDescription**. В противном случае приложение прервется при запуске. Дополнительную информацию об этом ключе см. в документации **Info.plist** от [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list).

Comment: Здравствуйте, возможно, я туплю, но вот что я сделал: прописал в файле CameraTest.pro QMAKE_INFO_PLIST = Info.plist, и автоматически создался фал info.polost, там я прописал  <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string>CameraTest</string>
    <key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
    <string>CameraTest</string>
    <key>NOTE</key>
    <string>This file was generated by Qt/QMake.</string> но ошибка все равно выскакивает. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: @CHICOTILA текст ошибки изменился?

Comment: Нет, текст ошибки такой же, как будто ничего не добавилось

Comment: Взгляните на этот баг https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-45357

Comment: Если вы редактировали этот файл через gui могла возникнуть проблема указанная в баге